# Assertion failure loading a file

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, assertion

I have got a code for .obj and .mtl files loading, there was assertion error so I put some assert functions and the error is at this part of code:

```
 assert(!mtlin.is_open(),"2");
            if(!mtlin.is_open())    //if not opened error message, clean all memory, return with -1
            {
                    std::cout << "connot open the material file" <<   std::endl;
                    clean();
                    return -1;
            }
```

I've tried with several .mtl files but all give assertion error!
Here is the complete code just in case:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "glut.h"
 #include <GL/gl.h>
 #include <GL/glu.h>
 #include "objloader.h"
 #include <assert.h> 
    //nothing to explain here
    coordinate::coordinate(float a,float b,float c)
    {
            x=a;
            y=b;
            z=c;
    }
    //nothing to explain here
    face::face(int facen,int f1,int f2,int f3,int t1,int t2,int t3,int m){
            facenum=facen;
            faces[0]=f1;
            faces[1]=f2;
            faces[2]=f3;
            texcoord[0]=t1;
            texcoord[1]=t2;
            texcoord[2]=t3;
            mat=m;
            four=false;
    }
    //nothing to explain here
    face::face(int facen,int f1,int f2,int f3,int f4,int t1,int t2,int t3,int t4,int m){
            facenum=facen;
            faces[0]=f1;
            faces[1]=f2;
            faces[2]=f3;
            faces[3]=f4;
            texcoord[0]=t1;
            texcoord[1]=t2;
            texcoord[2]=t3;
            texcoord[3]=t4;
            mat=m;
            four=true;
    }

    //nothing to explain here
    material::material(const char* na,float al,float n,float ni2,float* d,float* a,float* s,int i,int t)
    {
            name=na;
            alpha=al;
            ni=ni2;
            ns=n;
            dif[0]=d[0];
            dif[1]=d[1];
            dif[2]=d[2];

            amb[0]=a[0];
            amb[1]=a[1];
            amb[2]=a[2];

            spec[0]=s[0];
            spec[1]=s[1];
            spec[2]=s[2];

            illum=i;
            texture=t;
    }

    //nothing to explain here
    texcoord::texcoord(float a,float b)
    {
            u=a;
            v=b;
    }

    int objloader::load(const char* filename)
     {
    std::ifstream in(filename);     //open the model file
    if(!in.is_open())
    {
            std::cout << "Nor oepened" << std::endl; //if it's not opened then error message, and return with -1
            return -1;
    }
    char buf[256];  //temp buffer
    int curmat=0;   //the current (default) material is 0, it's used, when we read the faces
    while(!in.eof())
    {
            in.getline(buf,256);    //while we are not in the end of the file, read everything as a string to the coord vector
            coord.push_back(new std::string(buf));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<coord.size();i++) //and then go through all line and decide what kind of line it is
    {
            if((*coord[i])[0]=='#') //if it's a comment
                    continue;       //we don't have to do anything with it
            else if((*coord[i])[0]=='v' && (*coord[i])[1]==' ')     //if a vertex
            {
                    float tmpx,tmpy,tmpz;
                    sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"v %f %f %f",&tmpx,&tmpy,&tmpz);       //read the 3 floats, which makes up the vertex
                    vertex.push_back(new coordinate(tmpx,tmpy,tmpz));       //and put it in the vertex vector
            }else if((*coord[i])[0]=='v' && (*coord[i])[1]=='n')    //if it's a normal vector
            {
                    float tmpx,tmpy,tmpz;
                    sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"vn %f %f %f",&tmpx,&tmpy,&tmpz);
                    normals.push_back(new coordinate(tmpx,tmpy,tmpz));      //basically do the same
                    isnormals=true;
            }else if((*coord[i])[0]=='f')   //if it's a face
            {
                    int a,b,c,d,e;
                    if(count(coord[i]->begin(),coord[i]->end(),' ')==4)        //if this is a quad
                    {
                            if(coord[i]->find("//")!=std::string::npos)       //if it's contain a normal vector, but not contain texture coorinate
                            {
                                    sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d",&a,&b,&c,&b,&d,&b,&e,&b);      //read in this form
                                    faces.push_back(new face(b,a,c,d,e,0,0,0,0,curmat));    //and put to the faces, we don't care about the texture coorinate in this case
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            //and if there is no material, it doesn't matter, what is curmat
                            }else if(coord[i]->find("/")!=std::string::npos)        //if we have texture coorinate and normal vectors
                            {
                                    int t[4];       //texture coorinates
                                    //read in this form, and put to the end of the vector
                                    sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d",&a,&t[0],&b,&c,&t[1],&b,&d,&t[2],&b,&e,&t[3],&b);
                                    faces.push_back(new face(b,a,c,d,e,t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3],curmat));
                            }else{
                                    //else we don't have normal vectors nor texture coorinate
                                    sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"f %d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
                                    faces.push_back(new face(-1,a,b,c,d,0,0,0,0,curmat));          
                            }
                    }else{  //if it's a triangle
                                                    //do the same, except we use one less vertex/texture coorinate/face number
                                    if(coord[i]->find("//")!=std::string::npos)
                                    {
                                            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d",&a,&b,&c,&b,&d,&b);
                                            faces.push_back(new face(b,a,c,d,0,0,0,curmat));
                                    }else if(coord[i]->find("/")!=std::string::npos)
                                    {
                                            int t[3];
                                            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d",&a,&t[0],&b,&c,&t[1],&b,&d,&t[2],&b);
                                            faces.push_back(new face(b,a,c,d,t[0],t[1],t[2],curmat));
                                    }else{
                                            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"f %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
                                            faces.push_back(new face(-1,a,b,c,0,0,0,curmat));                                      
                                    }
                    }
    }else if((*coord[i])[0]=='u' && (*coord[i])[1]=='s' && (*coord[i])[2]=='e')     //use material material_name
    {
            char tmp[200];
            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"usemtl %s",tmp);      //read the name of the material to tmp
            for(int i=0;i<materials.size();i++)     //go through all of the materials
            {
                assert(strcmp(materials[i]->name.c_str(),tmp)==0,"1");
                    if(strcmp(materials[i]->name.c_str(),tmp)==0)   //and compare the tmp with the name of the material
                    {
                            curmat=i;       //if it's equal then set the current material to that
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }else if((*coord[i])[0]=='m' && (*coord[i])[1]=='t' && (*coord[i])[2]=='l' && (*coord[i])[3]=='l')      //material library, a file, which contain
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      //all of the materials
    {
            char filen[200];
            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"mtllib %s",filen);    //read the filename
            std::ifstream mtlin(filen);     //open the file
            assert(!mtlin.is_open(),"2");
            if(!mtlin.is_open())    //if not opened error message, clean all memory, return with -1
            {
                    std::cout << "connot open the material file" << std::endl;
                    clean();
                    return -1;
            }
            ismaterial=true;        //we use materials
            std::vector<std::string> tmp;//contain all of the line of the file
            char c[200];
            while(!mtlin.eof())
            {
                    mtlin.getline(c,200);   //read all lines to tmp
                    tmp.push_back(c);
            }
            char name[200]; //name of the material
            char filename[200];     //filename of the texture
            float amb[3],dif[3],spec[3],alpha,ns,ni;        //colors, shininess, and something else
            int illum;
            unsigned int texture;
            bool ismat=false;       //do we already have a material read in to these variables?
            strcpy(filename,"\0");  //set filename to nullbyte character
            for(int i=0;i<tmp.size();i++) //go through all lines of the mtllib file
            {
                    if(tmp[i][0]=='#')      //we don't care about comments
                            continue;
                    if(tmp[i][0]=='n' && tmp[i][1]=='e' && tmp[i][2]=='w')      //new material
                    {
                            if(ismat)       //if we have a material
                            {
                                    if(strcmp(filename,"\0")!=0)    //if we have a texture
                                    {
                                            materials.push_back(new material(name,alpha,ns,ni,dif,amb,spec,illum,texture)); //push back
                                            strcpy(filename,"\0");
                                    }else{
                                                    materials.push_back(new material(name,alpha,ns,ni,dif,amb,spec,illum,-1));              //push back, but use -1 to texture             
                                    }
                            }
                            ismat=false;    //we start from a fresh material
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"newmtl %s",name);        //read in the name
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='N' && tmp[i][1]=='s')      //the shininess
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"Ns %f",&ns);
                            ismat=true;
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='K' && tmp[i][1]=='a')      //the ambient
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"Ka %f %f %f",&amb[0],&amb[1],&amb[2]);
                            ismat=true;
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='K' && tmp[i][1]=='d')      //the diffuse
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"Kd %f %f %f",&dif[0],&dif[1],&dif[2]);
                            ismat=true;
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='K' && tmp[i][1]=='s')      //the specular
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"Ks %f %f %f",&spec[0],&spec[1],&spec[2]);
                            ismat=true;
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='N' && tmp[i][1]=='i')      //the I don't know what is this
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"Ni %f",&ni);
                            ismat=true;
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='d' && tmp[i][1]==' ')      //the alpha
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"d %f",&alpha);
                            ismat=true;
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='i' && tmp[i][1]=='l')      //the illum (don't ask)
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"illum %d",&illum);
                            ismat=true;
                    }else if(tmp[i][0]=='m' && tmp[i][1]=='a')      //and the texture
                    {
                            sscanf(tmp[i].c_str(),"map_Kd %s",filename);
                            texture=loadTexture(filename);  //read the filename, and use the loadTexture function to load it, and get the id.
                            ismat=true;
                    }
            }
            if(ismat)       //there is no newmat after the last newmat, so we have to put the last material 'manually'
            {
                    if(strcmp(filename,"\0")!=0)
                    {
                            materials.push_back(new material(name,alpha,ns,ni,dif,amb,spec,illum,texture));
                    }else{
                                    materials.push_back(new material(name,alpha,ns,ni,dif,amb,spec,illum,-1));                             
                    }
            }
    }else if((*coord[i])[0]=='v' && (*coord[i])[1]=='t')    //back to the obj file, texture coorinate
    {
            float u,v;
            sscanf(coord[i]->c_str(),"vt %f %f",&u,&v);     //read the uv coordinate
            texturecoordinate.push_back(new texcoord(u,1-v));       //I push back 1-v instead of normal v, because obj file use the upper left corner as 0,0 coorinate
            //but OpenGL use bottom left corner as 0,0, so I convert it
            istexture=true;
    }
    }
    if(materials.size()==0) //if some reason the material file doesn't contain any material, we don't have material
            ismaterial=false;
    else    //else we have
            ismaterial=true;
    std::cout << vertex.size() << " " << normals.size() << " " << faces.size() << " " << materials.size() << std::endl;     //test purposes
    //draw
    int num;
    num=glGenLists(1);      //I generate a unique identifier for the list
    glNewList(num,GL_COMPILE);
    int last=-1;    //the last material (default -1, which doesn't exist, so we use the first material)
    for(int i=0;i<faces.size();i++) //go throught all faces
    {
            if(last!=faces[i]->mat && ismaterial)   //if we have a meterial AND the last material is not the same
            {
                    //set all of the material property
                    float diffuse[]={materials[faces[i]->mat]->dif[0],materials[faces[i]->mat]->dif[1],materials[faces[i]->mat]->dif[2],1.0};
                    float ambient[]={materials[faces[i]->mat]->amb[0],materials[faces[i]->mat]->amb[1],materials[faces[i]->mat]->amb[2],1.0};
                    float specular[]={materials[faces[i]->mat]->spec[0],materials[faces[i]->mat]->spec[1],materials[faces[i]->mat]->spec[2],1.0};
                    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_DIFFUSE,diffuse);
                    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_AMBIENT,ambient);
                    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT,GL_SPECULAR,specular);
                    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,materials[faces[i]->mat]->ns);
                    last=faces[i]->mat;     //set the current to last
                    if(materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture==-1)       //if we don't have texture, disable it, else enable it
                            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                    else{
                            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture); //and use it
                    }
            }
            if(faces[i]->four)      //if quad
            {
                    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                            if(isnormals)   //if there are normals
                                    glNormal3f(normals[faces[i]->facenum-1]->x,normals[faces[i]->facenum-1]->y,normals[faces[i]->facenum-1]->z);    //use them

                            if(istexture && materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture!=-1)  //if there are textures
                                    glTexCoord2f(texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[0]-1]->u,texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[0]-1]->v);      //set the texture coorinate

                            glVertex3f(vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->x,vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->y,vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->z);

                            if(istexture && materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture!=-1)
                                    glTexCoord2f(texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[1]-1]->u,texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[1]-1]->v);

                            glVertex3f(vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->x,vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->y,vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->z);

                            if(istexture && materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture!=-1)
                                    glTexCoord2f(texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[2]-1]->u,texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[2]-1]->v);

                            glVertex3f(vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->x,vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->y,vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->z);

                            if(istexture && materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture!=-1)
                                    glTexCoord2f(texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[3]-1]->u,texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[3]-1]->v);

                            glVertex3f(vertex[faces[i]->faces[3]-1]->x,vertex[faces[i]->faces[3]-1]->y,vertex[faces[i]->faces[3]-1]->z);
                    glEnd();
            }else{
                    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                            if(isnormals)   //if there are normals
                                    glNormal3f(normals[faces[i]->facenum-1]->x,normals[faces[i]->facenum-1]->y,normals[faces[i]->facenum-1]->z);

                            if(istexture && materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture!=-1)
                                    glTexCoord2f(texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[0]-1]->u,texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[0]-1]->v);


                            glVertex3f(vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->x,vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->y,vertex[faces[i]->faces[0]-1]->z);

                            if(istexture && materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture!=-1)
                                    glTexCoord2f(texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[1]-1]->u,texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[1]-1]->v);

                            glVertex3f(vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->x,vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->y,vertex[faces[i]->faces[1]-1]->z);


                            if(istexture && materials[faces[i]->mat]->texture!=-1)
                                    glTexCoord2f(texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[2]-1]->u,texturecoordinate[faces[i]->texcoord[2]-1]->v);

                            glVertex3f(vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->x,vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->y,vertex[faces[i]->faces[2]-1]->z);
                    glEnd();
            }
    }
    glEndList();
    clean();
    lists.push_back(num);
    return num;
      }

      void objloader::clean()
      {
    //delete all the dynamically allocated memory
    for(int i=0;i<coord.size();i++)
            delete coord[i];
    for(int i=0;i<faces.size();i++)
            delete faces[i];
    for(int i=0;i<normals.size();i++)
            delete normals[i];
    for(int i=0;i<vertex.size();i++)
            delete vertex[i];
    for(int i=0;i<materials.size();i++)
            delete materials[i];
    for(int i=0;i<texturecoordinate.size();i++)
            delete texturecoordinate[i];
    //and all elements from the vector
    coord.clear();
    faces.clear();
    normals.clear();
    vertex.clear();
    materials.clear();
    texturecoordinate.clear();
     }

    objloader::~objloader()
     {
    //delete lists and textures
    for(std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator it=texture.begin();it!=texture.end();it++)
    {
            glDeleteTextures(1,&(*it));
    }
    for(std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator it=lists.begin();it!=lists.end();it++)
    {
            glDeleteLists(*it,1);
    }
    }

    //load the filename textures (only BMP, R5G6B5 format)
    unsigned int objloader::loadTexture(const char* filename)
    {
    //nothing new in here
    unsigned int num;
    glGenTextures(1,&num);
    SDL_Surface* img=SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,num);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,img->w,img->h,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,img->pixels);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);       //maybe just this
    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
    texture.push_back(num);
    return num;
    }

    objloader::objloader()
      {
    //at default we set all booleans to false, so we don't use anything
    ismaterial=false;
    isnormals=false;
    istexture=false;
     }
```

Comment: `assert(!mtlin.is_open(),"2");` will not ever fail (assuming you are using the standard [assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) macro).

Answer (score 1):

The `assert` macro only takes one parameter.

The compiler will be evaluating

```
!mtlin.is_open(),"2"
```

as one expression.  According to the `comma operator`, the result of the right most expression is what is returned.

So your `assert` is equivalent to:

```
assert("2")
```